# How to deploy python flask app on vercel?

Tags: flask, vercel

I want to deploy my python code on vercel. But the problem is it gaves me error Error: A Serverless Function has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 MB.

Here is my vercel.json file

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "app.py", "use": "@vercel/python" }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/app.py" }
  ]
}
```

Here is my requiremnt.txt:

````
bidict==0.22.1
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.6
h11==0.14.0
hpy==0.9.0
imutils==0.5.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
numpy==1.26.2
opencv-contrib-python==4.8.1.78
opencv-python==4.8.1.78
Pillow==10.1.0
python-engineio==4.8.0
python-socketio==5.10.0
setuptools==69.0.2
simple-websocket==1.0.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
wsproto==1.2.0
```
`
````